# Ubuntu on USB installation problem

Tags: boot, usb

A few days ago, I installed Ubuntu on USB and everything is working really well.

However, I probably did something wrong during the installation and now, every time I want to use Windows after Ubuntu, I have to open BIOS and change Windows boot to 1st instead of Ubuntu...

Is there anything I can do to repair that without losing everything?

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing wrong, nothing to repair. The problem is a misunderstanding of the UEFI boot process. If actually installed (Ubuntu) in external media, not just an installer and live session, then provided that drive is connected you may use Grub to boot both OSes; otherwise you need to change boot from UEFI settings > Boot just like you've been doing.

Comment: Did you install both Windows and Ubuntu in the same BIOS/UEFI mode? Once installed in same mode run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu's Terminal to add Windows to the boot menu.

Comment: @ChanganAuto oh ok, thank you!

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I'm not sure but could be that. I will try it, thank you!